# Localize Ionic/Capacitor Camera.getPhoto (From Photos / Take picture)

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

When using

Camera.getPhoto()

How can you localize the language of the share bar that is opened?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add a custom string when taking the picture instead of the default options: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/camera#imageoptions